# Low level programming C/C++

Tags: c++, c, low-level

I have been programming applications at the higher level for a while now and have just got interested in systems programming. What i want to do is, i want to build an OS (a primitive one) for fun...

But i know nothing about low level programming, i dont know anything about booting and stuff. I just want to know where to start and what to learn, I just started to learn about the booting stuff and filesystems but have no idea how to program them in C(++).

Managing hardware is another issue and i have no idea how to go about programming software to manage hardware..

One final problem is windows, i know how to generate windows in C++ graphics mode by drawing stuff on the screen, but programming languages like Java use things like JFrame to make windows and they basically hire the window style and stuff from the OS, so i dont know how to lend my Window style to the other programs that are running on my computer

Please help me and lead me in the right direction..

Comment: Google (and similar sites) is your friend. Use it! A good search term would be e.g. *os tutorial programming*.

Comment: I used this site after trying with Google

Comment: Look at this operating system course at MIT. The link contain all the materials(lectures,code,reference) for developing your own
http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/

Comment: how do you take the course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the text book about Xinu.  (Xinu Is Not Unix).  It takes you step by step building and operating system in C.

Comment: so do you mean i will be able to make an OS after reading the book and manage all the issues i mentioned in the question?>

Comment: Hmm.  More like a command line unix after you are done.  For controlling hardware, check out unix pages on modifying the kernel and writing device drivers.  For Windowing, I dunno.  Check out the history of X Windows, I guess.

Comment: okay.. but i'll have a raw OS rite? a one from which i can boot..

Comment: Yes.

http://www.xinu.cs.purdue.edu/

Comment: is the thing an ebook or should i buy it

Comment: I think you have to buy it.  10-20 buck used on ebay or amazon.